# BeautifulSoup: getting text outside of tags: unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I have some HTML string:

```
s="<html><body><div><p>inner text</p></div><p>middle text</p>outside text</body></html>"
```

and try to get the text:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
ps=soup.findAll("p")
for i in ps:
    print(i.text)
```

It gives:

```
inner text
middle text
```

Then I have a [web-page](http://www.wired.com/2016/08/review-samsung-galaxy-note-7/) when the structure is similar:

```
<article>
    <p>text1</p>
    <br>
    some outside text1
    <p>....</p>

    <br>
    some outside text2
</article>
</body>
```

But when I use

```
soup2=BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wired.com/2016/08/review-samsung-galaxy-note-7/", "html.parser")
ab=soup2.find("article", {"itemprop":"articleBody"})
ps=ab.findAll("p")
```

It gives me the outside text2 too.

Also there is a some form a javascript commercial (`<div id="wired-tired"`) after extracting which I can also get the outside text1. 
What's going on there?? How come can I get the second text searching only for `p` and why the first text also becomes available after removing `wired-tired`?

Comment: Although it may look like it's outside, from looking at the source code of the site, you can see that `outside text2` ends with a `p` tag. So in fact it is in a `p` tag somewhere and hence being located by `bs4`.

Comment: @ double_j  What text do you mean? For me outside text1 is  "Like the excellent S7 Edge, the 64GB Galaxy Note 7 comes with an all-star component list...." and outside text2="Oh, and you can unlock this phone by looking at it. It’s as cool as it sounds, and it works consistently. ". For the life of me, I can't see the `p`s there...

Comment: Yes that's the same text I'm referring to. Just so we're fully on the same page, I'm using Chrome and looking at the page source, not the element inspector.

Comment: @double_j 5, That's weird. The second text in element inspector is completely on its own. Now I see that the first text is inside `p` too, along with that `wired-tired` `div` but it wasn't visible in element inspector..

Comment: Now I see it. Couldn't get text from `p` while `wired-tired` was still there, after extracting it became possible. Thanks.